# htaccess visible by Web clients

Tags: .htaccess

I just discovered my .htaccess file is publicly visible from web clients (e.g. site/.htaccess ).

I'm running Apache/2.2.22 with mod_fcgid.

htaccess is working, if I put garbage in it I get Internal Server Error.

It seems these lines inside apache2.conf are ignored:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</Files>
```

Any hint?

**Update**
Inside conf.d directory there's a configuration file blocking some spambots and some ip ranges.

```
<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
# Forum Spambots
deny from IP-RANGE
deny from env=bad_bot
</Location>
```

How can I still block .htaccess and .htpasswd from being visible from web clients?

Comment: Remove the `satisfy all`

Comment: Removing    satisfy all    does not fix the problem.